# is it true that winrar cannot delete files inside tar file?

Tags: winrar

Can you please confirm that winrar cannot manipulate files inside tar?

Which program can I use it to delete files inside tar without unarchiving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[www.7-zip.org](http://www.7-zip.org) is a good option. Of course there's [`tar`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm). Please stop using `rar` post-haste (especially as it relates to torrents) thanks.

Oh, because `tar` was for magnetic tapes, it didn't used to support deleting files from the tape archive. `Gnu tar` previously linked does support it with [`--delete`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar). If this tar-file is compressed with `gzip` or `bzip2` you'll need to use the flag `-z` or `-j` and also have those ported tools on your system.